# c# determinar la calidad de imagen de un documento escaneado

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, scanner

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que escaneo un documento y lo guardo en una base de datos (no puedo guardar los documentos en un File Server u otro, deben estar en la base de datos).

Ahora mismo mi programa funciona pero los documentos que mete en la base de datos pesan mucho poniéndolos en alta calidad.

Cuando quiero escanear un documento, me sale esta ventana, en la que puedo elegir distintas opciones de escaneo. Me gustaría restringir el tipo de calidad que use la persona que escanea, es decir, que tuviera una calidad predeterminada y no pudiera cambiarse, de forma que no me saliera esta ventana:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Si no fuera posible esto, me gustaría disminuir el peso del documento de alguna forma.

Uso Visual Studio 2019.

Este es mi código:

```
public static void EscanearDocumento(string scannerId, PdfDocument doc, string cPlaca, string cNumProp)
{
   DeviceManager manager = new();
   Device disp = null;
   string dispDisponibles = "";

   if (manager.DeviceInfos[1].DeviceID == scannerId)
      disp = manager.DeviceInfos[1].Connect();
            
   if (disp == null)
   {
      foreach (DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
         dispDisponibles += info.DeviceID + "\n";
      
      throw new Exception("El dispositivo con el ID proporcionado no ha sido encontrado. Los dispositivos disponibles son:\n" + dispDisponibles);
   }

   ICommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
   try
   {
      Item item = disp.Items[1];
   }
    catch (COMException ex)
   {
      Excepciones.VerExcepciones(ex);
   }

    try
    {
       ImageFile imagen = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, WiaImageIntent.TextIntent,
       WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality, "{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}", true, true, false);

        try
        {
           ObtenerImagen(imagen, doc, cPlaca, cNumProp);
        }
        catch (COMException er)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
        }
     }
         catch (COMException er)
        {
           MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
        }
    }

private static void SetItem(IItem item, object property, object value)
{
   Property aProperty = item.Properties.get_Item(ref property);
            aProperty.set_Value(ref value);
}
```

En el método `ObtenerImagen`, paso la imagen obtenida del escáner a un documento pdf y lo comprimo, pero apenas baja el peso del archivo.

He intentado implementar este código donde está `Item item = disp.Items[1];` pero no me ha funcionado:

```
object something = 1;
Device item = manager.DeviceInfos.get_Item(ref something).Connect();
Item item = disp.Items[1];
SetItem(item, "6146", 4); // El color. [4 black and white, 2 grayscale, 1 color, 0 unspecified]
SetItem(item, "6147", 200); // Resolución horizontal
SetItem(item, "6148", 200); // Resolución vertical
SetItem(item, "6151", 200 * 8.5); // Área de escaneo horizontal.
SetItem(item, "6152", 200 * 11); // Área de escaneo vertical.
```

EDICIÓN: así es como muestro el documento:

```
private void MostrarDoc(DataTable dt)
{
byte[] ap = (byte[])dt.Rows[0]["documento"];
MemoryStream ms = new(ap);
pdfDocumentView1.Visible = true;
try
{
   pdfDocumentView1.Load(ms);
}
 catch (Exception ex)
{
MessageBox.Show("No es posible mostrar el archivo", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
}
```

Y de la siguiente forma obtengo la imagen escaneada:

```
private static void ObtenerImagen(Image img, PdfDocument doc, string contPlaca, string contNumPropuesta)
{
try
{
MemoryStream stream = new();
img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg);
XImage imagen = XImage.FromStream(stream);

PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
XGraphics graficos = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
graficos.DrawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
doc.Save(stream, false);

byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();

int cont = 0;
string userName = Environment.UserName;
string path = @"C:\Users\" + userName + @"\Downloads\GestionDocumental-";
while (File.Exists(path + cont + ".pdf"))
   cont++;
path = path + cont + ".pdf";

doc.Save(path);
MessageBox.Show("Bytes que ocupa la imagen: " + bytes.Length.ToString());

DataTable dt = new();
SqlCommand anadir = new(actualizar, con);
param.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contPlaca", contenidoPlaca);
param.Parameters.AddWithValue("@contNumPropuesta", contenidoNumeroPropuesta);
con.Open();
try
{
   anadir.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{
   MessageBox.Show("No se ha podido añadir el documento", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
            }
con.Close();

}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
MessageBox.Show("El proceso de escaneo fue interrumpido.", "Advertencia", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
}
}
```

Comment: ¿No sería mejor tener un File Server y guardar solo la ruta del archivo en la BD?

Comment: @luciacar capaz esto ayude https://ourcodeworld.com/articles/read/382/creating-a-scanning-application-in-winforms-with-csharp

Comment: ICommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog(); esta linea y esta linea ImageFile imagen = dialog.ShowAcquireImage(WiaDeviceType.UnspecifiedDeviceType, WiaImageIntent.TextIntent,  hacen que muestre esa ventana de dialogo, deberias usar scannerItem.Transfer como esta en el link que pase

Comment: @CarlosMarceloBuffaOrtíz gracias por la sugerencia, pero el problema con ```scannerItem.Transfer``` es que pone como predeterminado una calidad alta, que no sé si puedo cambiarla y me gustaría poner una más baja.

Comment: creo que puedes mirar a este repositorio y ver como esta echo, lo que quieres hacer se puede https://github.com/ourcodeworld/csharp-scanner-wia

Comment: @luciacar Has probado de cambiar la propiedad `WiaImageBias.MaximizeQuality` por `WiaImageBias.MinimizeSize`?

Comment: @Marc Sí, pero la calidad de imagen es muy mala.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Te dejo 2 formas para ajustarlo.**

1. **Scanner.Net** de nuget, solo necesitas el nombre del escaner, la ruta del archivo, el formato de imagen, true para pdf y establecer la configuracion, solo necesitarias guardar el archivo en la BD.

**Instalacion del paquete**

```
PM> Install-Package Scanner.Net
```

**Codigo**

```
ScanNet.ScanNet.ScanCfg cfg = new ScanNet.ScanNet.ScanCfg();
cfg.IntColor_Mode = 1;
cfg.IntResolution_DPI_Horizontal = 75;
cfg.IntResolution_DPI_Vertical = 75;
ScanNet.ScanNet.Scan("DSmobile 700D", @"C:\Users\Admin\Desktop\scan.pdf", "jpg", true, cfg);
```

2. Cambio de dialogo para no cargar la configuracion predeterminada y poder especificar los DPI, cambio de tipo de imagen de **WIA.ImageFile** a **System.Drawing** por que el tipo que elegiste da archivos muy grandes. Deberas guardar y cargar la imagen a tu PDF por que la funcion **ObtenerImagen** utilizaba el tipo de imagen **WIA.ImageFile** y si utilizas ese tipo el tamaño del archivo sera grande, te sugeriria usar el paquete para no tener que hacer esa programacion tambien.

[image: nuevo dialogo]

```
public static void EscanearDocumento(string scannerId, PdfDocument doc, string cPlaca, string cNumProp)
{
    DeviceManager manager = new DeviceManager();
    Device disp = null;
    string dispDisponibles = "";

    if (manager.DeviceInfos[1].DeviceID == scannerId)
        disp = manager.DeviceInfos[1].Connect();

    if (disp == null)
    {
        foreach (DeviceInfo info in manager.DeviceInfos)
            dispDisponibles += info.DeviceID + "\n";

        throw new Exception("El dispositivo con el ID proporcionado no ha sido encontrado. Los dispositivos disponibles son:\n" + dispDisponibles);
    }

    try
    {
        ICommonDialog dialog = new WIA.CommonDialog();
        Item item = disp.Items[1];
        //WIA_SCAN_COLOR_MODE = "6146";
        //WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6147";
        //WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_RESOLUTION_DPI = "6148";
        //WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6149";
        //WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_START_PIXEL = "6150";
        //WIA_HORIZONTAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6151";
        //WIA_VERTICAL_SCAN_SIZE_PIXELS = "6152";
        //WIA_SCAN_BRIGHTNESS_PERCENTS = "6154";
        //WIA_SCAN_CONTRAST_PERCENTS = "6155";
        SetItem(item.Properties, "6146", 1);
        SetItem(item.Properties, "6147", 75);
        SetItem(item.Properties, "6148", 75);
        //BMP = "{B96B3CAB-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
        //PNG = "{B96B3CAF-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
        //GIF = "{B96B3CB0-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
        //JPEG = "{B96B3CAE-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
        //TIFF = "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}";
        ImageFile img = (ImageFile) dialog.ShowTransfer(item, "{B96B3CB1-0728-11D3-9D7B-0000F81EF32E}", true);
        byte[] imgbte = (byte[])img.FileData.get_BinaryData();
        MemoryStream ms = new MemoryStream(imgbte);
        Image image = Image.FromStream(ms);
        image.Save("img.jpeg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
        //debes cargar la imagen de la ruta en donde se guardo
        ObtenerImagen(imagen, doc, cPlaca, cNumProp);
    }
    catch (COMException er)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(er.ToString());
    }
}

private static void SetItem(IProperties properties, object propName, object propValue)
{
    Property prop = properties.get_Item(ref propName);
    prop.set_Value(ref propValue);
}
```

Comment: Listo revisalo por favor acuérdate que el tipo de imagen cambio pero si se reduce el tamaño del archivo. Lo hice con 75 DPI a color,  en JPEG con una imagen y me dio 111 kbs. Me pareció bien.

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta, no he podido verla antes. ¿El tipo de ```imagen``` es ```Image```? El problema que tengo es que después tengo que pasarlo al tipo ```XImage``` para meter la imagen en un documento pdf.

Comment: XImage te genera una imagen muy pesada así no vas a aligerar el PDF utiliza mejor el paquete para crear el documento y lo guardas en la base de datos. O pon el  código donde guardas el PDF haber que se puede hacer.

Comment: Usando tu código y guardando la imagen en un ```XImage``` que después paso a pdf, está muy bien comprimido igualmente, pero al guardarlo en la base de datos y después mostrarlo, no se muestra nada. ¿De qué otra forma puedo guardar la imagen de tipo ```Image``` como pdf?

Comment: Si guardas el PDF en una ruta local puedes visualizarlo, ya intentaste validar el archivo que no tenga errores. https://www.pdf-online.com/osa/validate.aspx

Comment: Te refieres a que guarde el documento en una carpeta y desde ahí lo meta en la base de datos, ¿no? El archivo sí que es correcto, ya que otras veces he podido escanear el documento pero el tamaño era muy grande.

Comment: Si ya que con el cambio puede ser que la estructura sea invalida, debes poder visualizarlo y sobre todo debe pasar la validación. Solo seria una prueba para asegúrate que esta se puede visualizar correctamente y esta pasando la validación.

Comment: He guardado un pdf antes de que se guarde en la base de datos y otro después, el primero se ve y pasa la validación, pero el segundo no la pasa y me sale un mensaje diciendo que no puede abrirlo porque está dañado o no es del tipo admitido

Comment: Si me imaginaba que iba a ser un problema el cambio de tipo de Imagen, no pasa nada se puede arreglar, creo que estas guardando la pura imagen como byte array según lo que habías publicado antes solo que no tengo como lo muestras puedes también agregarlo por favor. https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/476086/c-minimizar-tama%c3%b1o-de-imagen

Comment: Puedes poner tambien  ObtenerImagen. por favor

Comment: Ya he conseguido arreglar el problema, siguiente este código, solo me faltaba cambiar la forma en que añadía el documento a la base de datos. Después de guardarlo en una ruta con ```doc.Save(path)```, leo los bytes con ```byte[] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);```, y guardo ese ```byte[]``` en la base de datos.

Answer (score 1):

Con `System.Drawing Bitmap.SetResolution` puedes hacerlo.

Te dejo este fragmento de código:

```
// This is to resize an image file biased to the width of the image
 public void ResizeImageProportionate_XInclination(Stream File_Stream, int Target_Width, string Save_Path)
 {
     try
     {
         // This to extract the image from the file stream without uploading
         System.Drawing.Image _image = System.Drawing.Image.FromStream(File_Stream);
         int Image_Width = _image.Width;
         int Image_Height = _image.Height;
         int target_width = Target_Width;
         int target_height = (Target_Width * Image_Height) / Image_Width;
         // This is to create a new image from the file stream to a specified height and width
         Bitmap _bitmap = new Bitmap(target_width, target_height, _image.PixelFormat);
         _bitmap.SetResolution(72, 72);
         // This is to resize the image to the target height and target width
         Graphics _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap);
         _graphics.DrawImage(_image, new Rectangle(0, 0, target_width, target_height),
            new Rectangle(0, 0, Image_Width, Image_Height), GraphicsUnit.Pixel);
         // This is to save the image file into the save path
         _bitmap.Save(Save_Path, _image.RawFormat);
         _image.Dispose();
         _graphics.Dispose();
         _bitmap.Dispose();
     }
     catch (Exception e)
     {
         throw e;
     }
 }
```

Éxitos.

Fuente: [Cambiar resolución de imagen C#](https://csharp.hotexamples.com/es/examples/System.Drawing/Bitmap/SetResolution/php-bitmap-setresolution-method-examples.html)

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta, pero en la línea ```Graphics _graphics = Graphics.FromImage(_bitmap);``` me salta la siguiente excepción: ```System.Exception: System.ArgumentException: A Graphics object cannot be created from an image that has an indexed pixel format. (Parameter 'image')```. ¿Sabes por qué puede ser?

Comment: También me he dado cuenta de que, al guardar el documento de esta manera: ```_bitmap.Save(Save_Path, _image.RawFormat);``` el tamaño del pdf es mayor que el que tenía antes.