# C# minimizar tamaño de imagen

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019, byte

Estoy haciendo un programa en el que escaneo un documento y lo guardo en una base de datos (no puedo guardar los documentos en un File Server u otro, deben estar en la base de datos).

Al escanear un documento, lo guardo al principio como una imagen, que posteriormente guardaré en un pdf. En algunos casos, el tamaño que adquiere el archivo es muy grande y me gustaría que como mucho llegara a 500KB.

Uso Visual Studio 2019.

¿Existe alguna forma de reducir el tamaño sin que disminuya mucho la calidad?

He intentado este código para reducirlo, pero hace lo contrario:

```
if(bytes.Length/1024 > 500)
{
   double scale = 1f;
   Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = new(img, new Size((int)(img.Width * scale), (int)(img.Height * scale)));
   MemoryStream resultStream = new();
   fullSizeBitmap.Save(resultStream, img.RawFormat);
   bytes = resultStream.ToArray();
   resultStream.Dispose();
   resultStream.Close();
   MessageBox.Show("Bytes al final: " + bytes.Length.ToString());
   scale -= 0.05f;
}
```

En `bytes` tengo la imagen escaneada en `byte[]` y `img` de tipo `Image`, aunque necesito que sea `XImage`.

Este es el código que uso para obtener la imagen:

```
byte[] imagenEnBytes = image.FileData.get_BinaryData();

MemoryStream ms = new(imagenEnBytes);
Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
XImage imagen = XImage.FromStream(ms);
PdfPage page = doc.AddPage();
page.Orientation = PageOrientation.Portrait;
XGraphics graficos = XGraphics.FromPdfPage(page);
            
graficos.DrawImage(imagen, 0, 0);
ms.Dispose();
MemoryStream stream = new();
doc.Save(stream, false);
byte[] bytes = stream.ToArray();
               
string actualizar = "UPDATE tabla SET documento = @documento WHERE p = @cp AND n = @cn;";
SqlCommand anadir = new(actualizar, con);
param.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cp", cp);
param.Parameters.AddWithValue("@cn", cn);
anadir.Parameters.AddWithValue("@documento", bytes);
 con.Open();
anadir.ExecuteNonQuery();
con.Close();
```

Comment: Y probaste algun proceso de compresion?

Comment: Guardala ccon otro formato la estas guardando como bmp y ademas Raw (original) busca como guardar con formato jpg y la calidad de la misma. Eso de la calidad tu debes determinar el grado de compresion.

Comment: @gbianchi intenté con esto, pero no comprimía nada ```using GZipStream compresor = new(ms, CompressionMode.Compress, false); compresor.Write(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);```

Comment: @MiguelZarate voy a intentar eso, gracias.

Comment: Hay formatos que por mas que trates de comprimirlos no se comprimen....

Comment: Escalar la imagen como lo realizas debería ser suficiente,:_ Bitmap fullSizeBitmap = new(img, new Size((int)(img.Width * scale), (int)(img.Height * scale)));  estas obteniendo una medida igual o mayor o es la calidad la que no es buena?

Comment: @Jorgesys no llego a ver el documento porque me da un error, pero el número de bytes aumenta bastante.

Comment: Es que un bmp, es el que mas tamano se lleva debes transformarlo por ejemplo a un jpg o png.

Comment: @Japv he probado a convertirlo a jpg, como uso ```XImage``` para guardar la imagen, he visto que tengo que hacer esto para poder ponerle un formato: ```Image img = Image.FromStream(ms);
img.Save(stream, ImageFormat.Jpeg); XImage imagen = XImage.FromStream(stream);``` Pero me da un error al intentar ver el documento, creo que es precisamente por esas líneas, pero no sé cómo hacerlo de otra forma.

Comment: Agrega mas codigo como estas obteniendo la imagen inicial, separa tu codigo por funcionalidad - metodos, para que sea mas facil separar la parte del nuevo formato de imagen, investiga algo mas sobre tipos de imagenes y compresion de las mismas.

Comment: Por otra parte, no te preocupes tanto, cuando tu guardas la imagen en una base de datos, la propia base de datos comprime la imagen.

Comment: @Japv ah vale, gracias. ¿Sabes cuánto puede llegar a comprimirla?

Comment: @luciacar, la comprime mucho